# GridviewCombobox values showing in Different Place

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a problem with GridViewComboBox column. For each row in GridViewComboBox has different items. When I select an item  in  first row of GridViewComboBox the items are displayed under the GridViewComboBox correctly but for the second time the the items are displayed at some other place of windows form and not in the GridView.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide some code to work upon?

Comment: Can you put your code here?